# android vision api не фокусируется

Tags: android, android-studio, api

изучаю android vision api т.к. нужно научить приложение распознавать штрихкоды

если картинка на мониторе то всё норм, а если напечатана -
 камера не фокусируется, даже если эту опцию включить

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples/barcode-reader

Comment: А что за устройство на котором тестируете? На эмуляторе пробовали через веб-камеру?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если используется `CameraSource`, то нужно в билдере прописать автофокус

```
cameraSource = new CameraSource
            .Builder(this, barcodeDetector)
            .setAutoFocusEnabled(true)
            .build();
```

И в манифесте прописать перед тегом `application`

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="true" />
```

В моем случае это помогло.